# Run the same suite 2 times with different params

Tags: angularjs, testing, protractor

Is there way to merge 2 commands into 1 command

- `protractor protractor.conf --suite create_buyer --params.buyerName=Buyer1`
- `protractor protractor.conf --suite create_buyer --params.buyerName=Buyer2`

like

- `protractor protractor.conf --suite create_buyer,create_buyer --params.suites[0].buyerName=Buyer1 --params.suites[1].buyerName=Buyer2`

to make this commad work i need to know the `current suite index`
is it possible?
may there is better way!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, there is no way you can do it using Protractor. However, if you want to run the same suite twice, then there is a better way of handling this situation using data-providers. There are many ways to create a data driven framework for protractor, but the easiest one that i feel is using [`jasmine-data-provider`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-data-provider), which is an npm package. Here's how you can do it -

Update conf.js file to include the suite and params -

```
suites: {
    create_buyer: ['./firstSpec.js'] //All your specs
},

params: {
    buyerName1: '',
    buyerName2: ''
},
```

Update all test scripts file to include the dataprovider -

```
//Require the dataprovider
var dp = require('/PATH_TO/node_modules/jasmine-data-provider'); //Update your path where the jasmine-data-provider is installed

//Usage of dataprovider in your specs
var objectDataProvider = {
    'Test1': {buyerName: browser.params.buyerName1},
    'Test2': {buyerName: browser.params.buyerName2}
};

dp(objectDataProvider, function (data, description) {

    //Whole describe or anything in the dp() runs twice
    describe('First Suite Test: ', function(){

        it('First Spec', function(){ 
            element.sendKeys(data.buyerName); //usage of the data buyerNames
            //Your code for the spec
        });

        //All your specs

    });
});
```

Now pass in the parameters using command prompt -

```
protractor protractor.conf --suite create_buyer --params.buyerName1=Buyer1 --params.buyerName2=Buyer2
```

**NOTE:** However the issue here is that you cannot run one single suite at a single stretch with one `buyerName`. For ex: You cannot run all specs in the suite `create_buyer` at one stretch using `buyerName1`.  Instead, one spec will run twice serially, once with `buyerName1` and `buyerName2`, then it continues to next spec. But i guess, that should also work if your requirement is to not use a strict flow for one buyer (i.e, to complete end-to-end testing of suite `create_buyer` with `buyerName1` and then run suite `create_buyer` with `buyerName2` - this shouldn't be the case as the thumb rule of automation says that one test script shouldn't depend on another).

Hope it helps